# mariabackup single table backup

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to use mariabackup as an alternative to mysqldump. Whilst trying to achieve a backup of a single table from a specific database, I am encountering some odd results.

Documentation used; https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partial-backup-and-restore-with-mariabackup/.

My setup consists on three DBs - employees, employees_2 and test_3. Within these DBs, there is the same table, data etc.. In other words, there are identical and the data has been downloaded from https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db.

As per documentation, I am using the following command;

`mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/var/tmp/test3_salaries_backup --database='test_3' --tables='salaries' --user=admin --password=password`

Expectation: Getting a backup in .ibd and .frm of the table **'salaries'** from the DB **'test_3'**.

OUTPUT:

```
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping mysql/transaction_registry.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping mysql/innodb_table_stats.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping mysql/innodb_index_stats.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping mysql/gtid_slave_pos.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping test_3/dept_emp.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping test_3/departments.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping test_3/employees.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping test_3/titles.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Copying ./test_3/salaries.ibd to /var/tmp/test3_salaries_backup/test_3/salaries.ibd
[00] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 >> log scanned up to (1042997581)
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03         ...done
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping test_3/dept_manager.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping employees/dept_emp.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping employees/departments.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping employees/employees.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Skipping employees/titles.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:03 Copying ./employees/salaries.ibd to /var/tmp/test3_salaries_backup/employees/salaries.ibd
[00] 2022-08-17 13:02:04 >> log scanned up to (1042997581)
[00] 2022-08-17 13:02:05 >> log scanned up to (1042997581)
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:05         ...done
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:05 Skipping employees/dept_manager.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:05 Skipping employees_2/dept_emp.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:05 Skipping employees_2/departments.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:05 Skipping employees_2/employees.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:05 Skipping employees_2/titles.
[01] 2022-08-17 13:02:05 Copying ./employees_2/salaries.ibd to /var/tmp/test3_salaries_backup/employees_2/salaries.ibd
```

However, what is happening is that the command is not just going to DB test_3 and copying the table. It is copying the table from all DBs, even though I specifically specified test_3 as can be seen from the output above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you needed to exclude databases. You simply had a typo in your first command... `--database` should've been `--databases`.

Since typos are [silently ignored](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariabackup-overview/#options), it didn't produce an error, but your command simply included all databases, as it ignored the unknown `--database` option

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this issue by using and amending the command to:

`mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/var/tmp/test3_salaries_backup --database='test_3' --databases-exclude='employees employees_2' --tables='salaries' --user=admin --password=password`